# Trigger not getting created in MariaDB

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I have a single table and I want to create a trigger on it but not able to do. Not getting any error in trigger syntax.

```
    CREATE TABLE AUTHER_TYPE
  (
    ID          int (11) NOT NULL ,
    AUTHER_TYPE   VARCHAR (2) ,
    AUTHER_NAME        VARCHAR (64) ,
    IS_ACTIVE   CHAR (1) ,
    CREATED_BY  VARCHAR (64) ,
    CREATE_DATE TIMESTAMP ,
    UPDATED_BY  VARCHAR (16) ,
    UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP
  ) ;




DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUTHER_TYPE_TRIGGER1 BEFORE DELETE ON AUTHER_TYPE FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '20002' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error Can not delete this record' ;
END ; //
DELIMITER ;
```

[image: This result is from GUI]
[image: This result from command line]
[image: This is show trigger result]

Comment: How did you verify if the trigger is created or not? Can you please screenshot "SHOW TRIGGERS 
FROM your_db_name;" result.

Comment: I have added the screenshot for SHOW TRIGGERS;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUTHER_TYPE_TRIGGER1 BEFORE DELETE ON AUTHER_TYPE FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '20002' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error Can not delete this record' ;
END// -- redefined delimiter
DELIMITER ;
```